# Getting STDOUT of system(); call in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to ask you if i call any application with system(); in PHP5 is it possible to get result of that application directly to php? (instead of doing SomeApp >> file.txt - and reading file in PHP).

For example: system('lynx page.html');
and i'd like to put result of 'lynx page.html' into variable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the [backtick operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php):

```
$out = `ls -a`;
```

You can also use `shell_exec("command")`, which is equivalent.

Comment: Also, `exec('command', $output)` will push each line of the output into `$output` (an _array_), which can sometimes be useful.